# Authenticating Angular Universal With JWT

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an Angular 10 Universal project that uses JWT retrieved from localhost in order to authenticate requests for private routes.

I currently use this project for the authentication process:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt

The problem I believe I am facing with Angular Universal is that when rendering pages that require authentication my requests are unable to retrieve the JWT token from localStorage. Note, this is what I think the issue is because I get a 401 unauthorized on these requests and have done some reading.

Is there any way to authenticate these requests using the JWT token that is returned when a user logs in to the website?

Backend is .Net Core 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you save JWT to cookies after receiving it? In that case JWT will be sent along with the request, so it can be processed on server side.
Also, i think it would be nice to set this cookie with secure flag, so it can't be accessed from js in case of xss vulnerability (so it cannot be sent to 3rd party service)

Comment: Yes. I was trying to avoid cookies but I assume I can. How do I add it to the right Header using Universal? Do you know?

Comment: Are you talking about passing generated jwt after authorization to front or sending received earlier jwt from front to server?

Comment: I need to send an authenticated request from the Angular Universal renderer to my API so requests from front end to back end need to get that header with the token. The front end gets it in an object sent from the API.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can, for example, use ngx-cookie https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie#-server-side-rendering to get jwt sent from frontend with CookieService, then you can pass it to your backend with help of http interceptor which will get value from cookieservice and append it to headers

Comment: Hi sorry I had figured out my issue. Put that Github link in your answer? If you do I will accept it as the right answer because I do believe it would have solved my problem in another way. Thanks!